# How to specify anchor after a node name calculated by \pgfmathsetmacro?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm learning TikZ and trying to create an FFT diagram similar the [one here](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/radix2fft/).

So far, I've got the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [ yscale=-1,
      dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5mm}]
  \begin{scope}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3} {
      \node (a\y) at (0, \y) [dot, label=left:$x(\y)$] {};
      \node (b\y) at (4, \y) [dot] {};
      \draw[->] (a\y) -- (b\y);
    }

    \foreach \y in {0,...,1} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\othery{\y+2};
      \draw[->] (a\y.east) -- (b\othery);
      \draw[->] (a\othery) -- (b\y.west);
    }

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The downward diagonal arrows are unfortunately connecting to the east anchor instead of the west, but I am unable to add `.west` (i.e. `\draw[->] (a\y.east) -- (b\othery.west);`) because it gives me the error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `w' or `we' (in '0.west').
```

How do I have the downward diagonal arrows connecting at the west anchor instead? Or maybe this is the wrong approach and there is a better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` or any other means that avoids putting `.0` after the result of the computation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [ yscale=-1,
      dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5mm}]
  \begin{scope}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3} {
      \node (a\y) at (0, \y) [dot, label=left:$x(\y)$] {};
      \node (b\y) at (4, \y) [dot] {};
      \draw[->] (a\y) -- (b\y);
    }

    \foreach \y in {0,...,1} {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\othery{\y+2};
      \draw[->] (a\y.east) -- (b\othery);
      \draw[->] (a\othery) -- (b\y.west);
    }

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, in simple cases like this one you can just use `\the\numexpr` to avoid parsing altogether. (I added `\relax` so that you can add anchors if needed.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [ yscale=-1,
      dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5mm}]
  \begin{scope}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3} {
      \node (a\y) at (0, \y) [dot, label=left:$x(\y)$] {};
      \node (b\y) at (4, \y) [dot] {};
      \draw[->] (a\y) -- (b\y);
    }

    \foreach \y in {0,...,1} {
      \draw[->] (a\y.east) -- (b\the\numexpr\y+2\relax);
      \draw[->] (a\the\numexpr\y+2\relax) -- (b\y.west);
    }

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgive the question of a newbie. What does `\relax` do?

Comment: @Roxy It avoids that the `\the\numexpr` scans any further. That is, `\the\numexpr\y+2\relax+3`, say, will only look at `y+2`, but ignore the `+3` afterwards. This can be important if you want to add an anchor, e.g. `\the\numexpr\y+2\relax.180`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!